# How to call multiple arrays in a void method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am stuck on how to call my method.
I get a cannot find symbols (playerName,battingArray) error message.
-Am I not calling it correctly?
-Is the method set up to populate the arrays properly?

I am not even sure if this is the best way to go about doing this.

ANY HELP IS SO GREATLY APPRECIATED!!

```
//Import util to accept input
import java.util.Scanner;


    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Assign number of players to variable and call method readNumPlayers
        int numPlayers = readNumPlayers();
        System.out.println(numPlayers);

        //Call readData method
        readData(playerName, numPlayers, battingArray);

}//end main

    //readNumPlayers method
    public static int readNumPlayers() {
        System.out.println("Number of players: ");
        int numPlayers = input.nextInt();
        if (numPlayers <=0) {
            System.out.println(" Error- Try again ");
            System.out.println("Number of players: ");
            numPlayers = input.nextInt();
        }//end catch to ensure entry is positive integer
        return numPlayers;  //return
    }//end readNumPlayers


    //readData method
    public static void readData(String[] playerName, int numPlayers,
                                double[] battingArray) {
        playerName = new String[numPlayers];
        System.out.println("Enter player's last name: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < playerName.length; i++) {
            playerName[i] = input.next();
        }  //end for loop

        battingArray = new double[numPlayers];
                System.out.println("Enter player's batting average: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < battingArray.length; i++) {
            battingArray[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }// end for loop


      }//end readData

}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking about. Can you clarify what exactly you need help with?

Comment: It seems you're aking how to create arrays. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html. You need to create 2 arrays (actually, 3, given the instructions), and pass them as arguments to your readData() method.

Comment: I guess you need to enclose your code in a `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the arrays as parameters the caller of `readData` is supplying ***references** to* the arrays to fill in, and, while you can affect the contents of the array referenced you can't change the reference itself — so you should not allocate arrays in your method - for example, your line:
`battingArray = new double[numPlayers];`

When you allocate a new array and fill that in, the caller has no access to that array, and you have not put anything in the array that the caller passed (and *does* have access to)
Just use the `double[] battingArray` parameter that the caller passed in.

Here are two versions of a very simple example; in the first the `readData` method allocates it's own array and fills it in. You'll see that when `main` prints the array content you get `null` because the array filled by readData is not the same array that was passed.

In the second, readData just puts values into the array that the caller passed.

First:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int count = 2;
    String[] names = new String[count];
    double[] avgs = new double[count];
    readData(names, avgs, count);
    System.out.println("names[0] in main: " + names[0]);
  }

  public static void readData(
    String[] playerNames,
    double[] battingAvg,
    int numPlayers
  )
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // allocating a new array
    String[] playerNames2 = new String[numPlayers];
    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
    {
      System.out.print("Players name: ");
      String line = in.nextLine();
      // putting the value into the newly allocated array
      playerNames2[i] = line.trim();
    }
    System.out.println("playerNames2[0] in readData: " + playerNames2[0]);
  }
}
```

Second:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int count = 2;
    String[] names = new String[count];
    double[] avgs = new double[count];
    readData(names, avgs, count);
    System.out.println("names[0] in main: " + names[0]);
  }

  public static void readData(
    String[] playerNames,
    double[] battingAvg,
    int numPlayers
  )
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // no array allocated this time
    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
    {
      System.out.print("Players name: ");
      String line = in.nextLine();
      // put the value into the array that was passed
      playerNames[i] = line.trim();
    }
    System.out.println("playerNames[0] in readData: " + playerNames[0]);
  }
}
```

Since the caller is telling you how big the arrays are (`numPlayers` parameter), let's say "10", if the caller's arrays aren't actually big enough (say they did `new String[5]`) it's possible that you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, so `readData` would probably want to catch that and return without finishing the loop.

(I've created a [Java repl](https://repl.it/@stephen61/Testing-for-SO-55226168) where you can see version 2)